# How can I use a Chinese Samsung Galaxy Note 3 SM-N9008S in Iran?

Tags: rom-flashing, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I bought a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 SM-N9008S in China. I can not install Google Play Services and there are only Chinese and Korean languages built in. I did not know Samsung manufacture mobiles according to region; I think this a disadvantage in Samsung product management.

I am living in Iran I would like to install Google Play Services, as well as add the Persian and English languages. How can I do this?

Comment: You could look up how to flash cyanogenmod, and the flash that rom.

Answer (score 1):

[Sammobile](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/1/?model=SM-N9008S&pcode=0#firmware) only lists the Chinese ROM for your device, so it's unlikely you'll be able to use different languages with an official Samsung ROM: to get other languages and Google apps support, you'll need to use a third-party [custom-rom](/questions/tagged/custom-rom). Similarly, it doesn't appear that the N9008S is an officially supported device for Cyanogenmod, likely because none of the developers have one.

There's [a thread on the XDA Developers forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2502508), but it doesn't make your prospects look good. [Googling for *cyanogenmod N9008S*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=cyanogenmod%20n9008s) produces a lot of noise (rooting guides, and pages that mention N9008S but are actually about other devices), as well as one or two pages that *might* have unofficial ROMs but are in Chinese, so you'll have to trawl through them with Google Translate to see if any are actually helpful. You might find that as they're in Chinese, they've only ported a Chinese build of Cyanogenmod, which would leave you no better off.

In any case, you should be very wary of unofficial ROM builds, since they could backdoor your device or contain other malware, and you should be extra-careful about following flashing instructions in a language you don't understand. Only try something out if you're willing to risk bricking your phone.